# Problems checking SQL Broker objects before creating them

Tags: sql-server, messagebroker, broker

Is there any way to check SQL Broker before creating then?
I really need to skip in case of existing object:

```
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE MessageType
AUTHORIZATION dbo
VALIDATION = None;

CREATE CONTRACT MessageContract 
(MessageType SENT BY ANY);
```

I'd like to try something like "IF EXISTS", but I didn't find the proper systable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the *Message type* using

```
exists(
  select * from sys.service_message_types 
  where [name] = 'MessagetypeName'
);
```

Likewise you can check for the above `message_type_id` in `sys.service_contracts`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do it using sys tables like:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from sys.service_message_types where name = 'MessageType')
begin
    CREATE MESSAGE TYPE MessageType
    AUTHORIZATION dbo
    VALIDATION = None;
end
```

thanks